# Order of multypling 2 sub-groups who's orders are coprime

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Im given as an exercize to prove that an order of 2 sub-groups A,B who's orders are coprime, is: $$|A| \cdot |B|$$

What I know that generally: $$|AB|=\frac{\left|A\right|\cdot \left|B\right|}{\left|A\bigcap B\right|}$$

I looked at my proof that I was given in class and there is no mention for any relativity to the order of $A$ or $B$ or the intersection. So I dont have a clue. Anybody can help me with this?

Comment: BTW, it is not normal practice to hyphenate subgroup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take an element $g\in A\cap B$. Then the order of $g$ divides both $|A|$ and $|B|$. Since their cardinality is coprime, the order of $g$ is $1$, namely $g$ is the trivial element.

Therefore 
$$|A\cap B|=1.$$